# how to Replace a Column values of my database with other value of different column in same table in mysql

Tags: mysql

```
id  id2 body
1   5   cat 
2   6   bat
3   1   dgdfgdfg
4   4   rat
5   3   sdfsdfsdfs
6   2   sdfsdf
```

Mysql Query to get result like this

```
id  id2             body
1   sdfsdfsdfs      cat 
2   sdfsdf          bat
3   cat             dgdfgdfg
4   rat             rat
5   dgdfgdfg        sdfsdfsdfs
6   bat             sdfsdf
```

i need a mysql query to get that result. sorry for asking this basic question. i did a lot search before putting ths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.id, IFNULL(t2.body, t1.id2) AS id2, t1.body
FROM YourTable AS t1
LEFT JOIN YourTable AS t2 ON t2.id = t1.id2
```

Comment: Your question said you wanted to replace the column, that sounds like updating. I've changed my answer to a `SELECT` query that shows that result.